# Blank white empty page in Laravel 5.x

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

When I validate my form the server returns a blank white empty page without any error.

**Related code part:**

```
return view('ajoutQuestion')->with(array('numQest'=>$numQest,'idQ'=>$request->get('idQ')));
```

Comment: what does view `ajoutQuestion` contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved the problem, i was using the same name for multiple inputs